# How to make user logout via twitch API?

Tags: php, api, twitch, twitch-api

i' am working on a website in which I have to make a functionality for voting a specific channel so the requirement is that the user who is voting he must log in to vote a channel so how do i validate that this user is logged in or not because there is no Twitch API for logout. So as far as i have work on Twitch API i see this thing when i login via twitch in my website it logged you in on a Twitch site as well so as long as you are login in Twitch site you are also login in your site because of it takes a parameter of "redirect_uri" in login API as far as i assume. and if i create a session on user login and destroy it on my custom made log out it will always login in the my site because it is login in Twitch site.

Comment: So you basically want to check if a user is logged in rather?

Comment: yes, if logged in than vote otherwise not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to revoke the token, like that :

```
POST https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/revoke
    ?client_id=<your client ID>
    &token=<your OAuth token>
```

https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication/#revoking-access-tokens